# displaying iphone movie controlls on touch

Tags: iphone, video, sdk

i have the video controlls set to hidden in my app with the code

```
   [mp setMovieControlMode:MPMovieControlModeHidden];
```

this sets in hidden for the whole video.
what i want to do is have the controls hidden at the start but if the screen is pressed then have the controls display any suggestions? would be much appreciated.

Comment: `C` tag removed. I've added tags that seemed relevant; sorry if I overdid it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a good answer here:

[How to hide control before MPMoviePlayerController movie is played?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3961137/how-to-hide-control-before-mpmovieplayercontroller-movie-is-played)

Comment: ok i put in the code as follows bt it still doesnt show any of the controlls when i touch the screen.

Comment: [mp setControlStyle:MPMovieControlStyleNone];

Comment: [mp performSelector:@selector(setControlStyle:) withObject:nil afterDelay:1];