# How to show MPMoviePlayerController controls?

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, mpmovieplayercontroller

I have MPMoviePlayerController, and I want to show controls programmaticaly, like after user's tap, or simulate users tap.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/KYMmG.jpg (Sorry, I don't have enough reputation, to post images).]

How can I do this?
Thanks.

Comment: check if you can add the image now..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

creating the MPMoviePlayerController object in the following way would give you an interface for video controls

```
yourMoviePlayerController = [MPMoviePlayerController new];     
yourMoviePlayerController.controlStyle=MPMovieControlStyleEmbedded;
[yourMoviePlayerController setContentURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:videoPath]];
yourMoviePlayerController.backgroundView.hidden = YES;

[yourMoviePlayerController setScalingMode:MPMovieScalingModeAspectFit];
yourMoviePlayerController.shouldAutoplay=YES;
yourMoviePlayerController.movieSourceType = MPMovieSourceTypeFile;
```

Answer (score 1):

Someone already answer to that question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3961137/how-to-hide-control-before-mpmovieplayercontroller-movie-is-played?answertab=votes#tab-top) i think

Set `controlStyle` property to `MPMovieControlStyleNone` initially, and then set it to `MPMovieControlStyleFullscreen` one second later using a `[performSelector:withObject:afterDelay:1]`. It works well, controls do not appear until user taps on video.